# Sort an enumerable in descending order

Tags: ruby, enumerable

What's the best way to sort an `Enumerable` in descending order?

I've been doing `@array.sort.reverse` or `@array.sort_by{|song| song.title }.reverse`

I suppose I could do something like `@array.sort{|a, b| b.title <=> a.title}`, but I find this hard to read and verbose.

Comment: I think `array.sort.reverse` is good. It's simple and clear, and shouldn't be very expensive.

Comment: Why wouldnt you use #reverse?

Comment: Since sort is `O(n log n)` and reverse is just `O(n)`, Peter's solution is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The performance of `Array.reverse` is not *very* bad. What costs you by using `@array.sort.reverse` is an extra array duplication plus the reverse (n/2 element switches). So yes, I think that should be acceptable if you think it's read clearer.

See its [source](http://ruby-doc.org/doxygen/1.8.4/array_8c-source.html#l01542) for details. And also, I think using `@array.sort.reverse` does provide 'slightly' better readability (but it's not very hard to read any way).

Comment: sort.reverse is not much slower than sort, and it's way faster than anything fancy.  I benchmarked array.sort, array.sort.reverse, and array.reverse_sort (my monkey-patch solution, which I've since deleted as "an obvious piece of junk") on 1,000,000 random floats and got times of 2.4, 2.5 and 24.8 seconds, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure whether this works any better than [Wayne Conrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238886/wayne-conrad)'s self-described "obvious piece of junk," but you could define `Enumerable#sort_by_descending` as

```
Enumerable.class_eval do
  def sort_by_descending(&block)
    sort { |a, b| block.bind(b).call <=> block.bind(a).call }
  end
end
```

Then call it as follows:

```
@songs.sort_by_descending(&:title)
```